# Linking list items automatically

Tags: list

Whats the best way to go about this:

I have a user list that someone enters item information in. Then a user enters an item, we want to have that item automatically created in an identical admin list. Then be able to change some fields in the admin list. These edited fields will then be updated to the user list when changed in the admin list.

Comment: Go Rockets btw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say using workflow to do it but it could get messy if not planned appropriately.

The destination list will need to have a lookup column to the source list to maintain referential integrity or things could get out of sync. When a user creates an item in the source list, it creates an item in the destination list and sets the lookup column to link them together.

Then in the destination list you would have a workflow that rights to the source list, looking up what item to update via the lookup column.

This would require that users on the source list have access to add items to the destination list, unless you plan to add an impersonation step in the workflow.

Comment: If I have a workflow on both lists that starts when an item is modified, will this cause an infinite loop because the workflows will keep modifying the list?

Comment: No, the system should not allow that to happen.

Comment: Okay well I'll will let you know pretyy soon, ha

Comment: Hmmm kind of strange actaully, I use nintex workflow instead on sharepoint designer. So I make the change on one list and it will do the change then there are 5 more versions added after that but those are making no change. So it seems as if it does loop but then stops. I do need to make some changes to this somehow though because I want proper versioning

Comment: 5 more versions of what? Not sure what you are trying to do exactly, the workflows are only going to affect the related item, a 1 to 1 update of the source and child. Where is this one to many versioning thing happening?

Comment: I have the two lists and when they are modified the workflow is set to run automatically. So if I change a column in list1, it will run the workflow and change that column in list2. But then I think that workflow on list2 runs again because it is set to start when the list is modified.